# Book about a person who fell from somewhere into San Antonio and developed superpowers

Tags: story-identification, books, childrens-novel

I read a book some years ago. It was about a person who fell from somewhere (not sure where) into San Antonio (maybe he fell, maybe he just walked, I don't really remember.) He then became a person with superpowers (I don't know which.) Here's the thing: I remember it asking us to play "America the Beautiful" in our heads very often.

Is there a book that matches this criteria? It was a children's book, I think.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, when you say _"I remember it asking us to play "America the Beautiful" in our heads very often."_, who or what is the "it" in that sentence?

Comment: I read this a few years ago, and given the cartoonish nature of the thing (Sliiiiightly like Captain Underpants in San Antonio) it seems like it was published a few years back. The "it" is the book itself, it said something on the lines of *Play America the Beautiful in your head* at some moments.